# Using Quotation operator in sql in dynamic query

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am facing an issue,when I have to use quotation operator in function call.

For example:

```
Select replace( vstring, Cust_ref_Id, Vdata(vcount).cust_ref_id)
From dual;
```

Now my value of cust_ref_id holds Apostrophe.
Which I tried to handle using

```
Select replace( vstring, Cust_ref_Id, Vdata(vcount).q'[cust_ref_id]')
From dual;
```

But it's not working.
I have to tell `Oracle` that it needs to handle the apostrophe coming in the value you are receiving from `Vdata(i).cust_ref_id.`

How can I do that?

Comment: You haven't really explained what the problem is, do you get an error when you try to run your statement? (You shouldn't in a `SELECT`). Can you post the SQL for the function you're trying to run?

Comment: Since you are querying the DUAL table, nothing in your SELECT is the name of a column in a database table. So they must all be variables. I suggest you [edit] your question and replace all the variables with their actual values. Then I would be able to test your query myself and see why it's not working and what needs to be changed in order to get it working.